# moving list items from wss 3.0 to foundation 2010 using lists.asmx

Tags: list, caml-query, updatelistitems

I'm trying to use [Lists.UpdateListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to move items from a list in WSS 3.0 to a list in SharePoint Foundation 2010. The original list contains several items. The target list does not contain any items.

When I run the code, no items are added to my 2010 list.

Here is the CAML I'm generating for the first item:

```
<Method ID='237' Cmd='New'>
<Field Name='ID'>237</Field>
<Field Name='Title'>237x</Field>
<Field Name='SampleID'>B000004</Field>
</Method>
```

I'm not getting any error messages. What is going wrong?

**UPDATE**

I am able to move list items from the WSS 3.0 production server to SharePoint Foundation 2010 on my local machine. However, when I try to move the items from the WSS 3.0 production server to our Foundation 2010 production server, I have the original problem (the list items don't move and I don't get an error). Does this seem like my account needs higher permissions on the 2010 production server? Or is there a code-based way to give myself higher permissions? Or is the problem unrelated to permissions?

Comment: I think even if the method fails it wont return an error you should extract the result of the web service code. the result is in xml format whether the method is successful and even if it fails it would return an xml fragment. can you post more details on your code so that we can see how are you using the web service itself. but to resolve the problem itself i think you just need to use an account with higher priviledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be unrelated to the XML or privileges. The URL I used to hit lists.asmx on the production site was pointing to the root of the site instead of to the web where my list is. So I was using

```
http://mysite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx
```

when I should have used

```
http://mysite/web1/web2/_vti_bin/lists.asmx
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Ranjoe,

you should go step by step like:
1.Privilege account.
2. As you said you web service target the root site list, use the tool [soapui](http://www.soapui.org/%E2%80%8E) to connect your service with it and you can update the record also from this tool.Here you can find out the error of your web service.